# ExtentHtmlReporter can't create the report.html

Tags: selenium

Please help!!
I try to use the ExtentHtmlReporter to create a costume report name like "MyReport.html" but it generate an "index.html" file instead.
By the way I'm using ExtentReports 4.1.0. and C# in VS 2019.
Here is my code

```
        //var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("C:\\DevEnvironment\\MyReport.html");
        var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"C:\DevEnvironment\MyReport.html");
        htmlReporter.Config.Theme = Theme.Standard;
        htmlReporter.Config.DocumentTitle = "My Test Report";
        htmlReporter.Config.ReportName = "Positive and Negative Test";
        _extent.AddSystemInfo("Environment", "OS Widows");
        _extent.AddSystemInfo("User Name", "Qlee");
        _extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior with the version4 HtmlReporter. It creates upto 4 files depending upon the attributes that are created. This is also true for all new version4 reporters, to maximize performance and obviously to keep each file focused on its specific tasks.

If you would like the old behavior, use the version3 port of HtmlReporter:

var v3html = new ExtentV3HtmlReporter()